# Broadcast a message by server and receive response from each client and store clients IP address and client machines user name

Tags: c#, client-server, broadcasting

I have this code which send the IP address of client but it show only one clients IP My code is

Server Side

```
 var Client = new UdpClient();
    var RequestData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Server Data");
    var ServerEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    Client.EnableBroadcast = true;
    Client.Send(RequestData, RequestData.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 8888));

    var ServerResponseData = Client.Receive(ref ServerEp);
    var ServerResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ServerResponseData);
    Console.WriteLine("Recived {0} from {1}", ServerResponse, ServerEp.Address.ToString());

    Client.Close();
```

Client Side

```
 var sever = new UdpClient(8888);
        var responedata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Client data");
        while (true)
        {
            var ClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            var clientrequestdata = sever.Receive(ref ClientEP);
            var clientrequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientrequestdata);
            Console.WriteLine("Recived {0} from {1}, sending response", clientrequest, ClientEP.Address.ToString());
            sever.Send(responedata, responedata.Length, ClientEP);
```